# Azure Mvc website never opens up locally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, http-status-code-404

My Mvc website never opens up locally. It tries to search the website, but is unable to and in the end a 404 is displayed.

Please help on this, if you can.

I have one webrole (Mvc website) and two worker roles (WCF services) communicating with worker roles.

It works fine on Azure servers though...

It sometimes throws an error while running that `Role Instances are taking longer than expected` and I have to restart my system to make it running again (i.e., to reach up to the 404 error again)...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your local SQL Server instance is not running or misconfigured. It uses SQL Server to support table storage and other local resources. Check out DSInit to configure your database. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433134.aspx

Also, did you launch Visual Studio as an Administrator? You'll need to right click on Visual Studio and select "Run as administrator" in the context menu. I had the same experience a while back and I had forgot to do that step. This is required to run an Azure solution locally.